# Justifying List texts in MS Word 2007 Document

Tags: microsoft-word

I have created a list in MS Word, but when I try to justify the text of each line, it's not working.

How can I justify text in a list in MS word?

Comment: Does each bullet point span multiple lines? If it's just one or two words per bullet point it won't justify. This is also true for regular paragraphs.

Comment: Yes, it does span multiple line.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot? (Use dummy text that mimics what your document looks like or otherwise obscure it if you wish.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other answers didn't quite work out the way I wanted it to. I had to resort to creating a new Doc and retype older contents.

Answer (score 0):

In order to justify text, list or not) it needs to wrap to a second line. Please see the included screenshot for a demonstration.

[image: Word - Justify Demo]